# Larvel Eloquent Model save function is not saving but not error

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

My problem at the moment is that I want to save some values to the database but the don't get saved and I don't get an error..

Both, either `$product-save();` or `$product-update(array(...))` are not working and I cannot tell why.. My ASIN Model looks fine and is filled with the right fillable attributes...

You guys know why it isn't working?

My Laravel Version: `Laravel Framework 5.5.36`

This is my class so far:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\ASIN;

class CheckPrice extends Command
{

    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'post:CheckPrice';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle() {

        $product = ASIN::find(1410);

        $product->price = "HELLO";
        $product->amountSaved = "HELLO";
        $product->percentageSaved = "HELLO";
        $product->url = "HELLO";
        $product->imgUrl = "HELLO";
        $product->save();

        //$product->update(array("price" => "HELLO", "amountSaved" => "HELLO", "percentageSaved" => "HELLO", "url" => "HELLO", "imgUrl" => "HELLO"));

        $this->printProduct(ASIN::find(1410));
    }
```

My ASIN Model so far:
    namespace App;

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ASIN extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'facebook_amazon';
    public $table = "ASINS";

    protected $fillable = [
        'ASIN',
        'price',
        'amountSaved',
        'percentageSaved',
        'category',
        'url',
        'imgUrl',
        'showApp'
    ];
}
```

Kind regards and Thank You!

Comment: are you validating the data through validate function?

Comment: there might be spelling mistake and it might not match with the table columns.

Comment: I am not validating the data and the column names are correct. I have copied and pasted them

Comment: Call `save` function inside a `try catch` block, see if there is any problem with your connection to the database or not

Comment: Not working as well... But I defintily do have a connection otherwise I couldn't print the product attributes to the console!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in the handle methode

```
$product = App\ASIN::find(1410);
```

Or while impoting ASIN model use this if you want to keep the handle methode same

```
use App\ASIN as ASIN;
```

Comment: Is the parameter in your find() method is any of the values of primary keys in ANSI model. Check if the model is retrieved in the first place.

Comment: It is retrieving the first place as well!

Comment: Yep! It has both columns!

Comment: Try this $product->fill(['filed_1' => 'value' , 'field_2' => 'value']);

Comment: Is the primary key coulmn_name "id" check or anything else check also case sensitivity?

Comment: change the column name from "ID" to "id". Your id column is capitalized or in the model define the it like this protected $primaryKey = 'ID'; laravel assumes your primary key is "id"

Comment: :) pleased to help

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel logs:

```
if(!$product->save()){
foreach($products->errors() as $error){ 
Log::info($error);
}
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Are you sure your command is running? try add Log at the beginning of the handle function.

Comment: Yeah, it is definitly running!!

Comment: And also make sure your connection is right, and you are not writing data into wrong db

Comment: are you able to retrieve data?
$product = ASIN::find(1410);
dd($product );

try use forceSave method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183080/discussion-between-osama-alvi-and-jan).